# Isn't "rural" redundant in "rural village"?

Tags: usage

My question is simple. Isn't "rural" redundant in "rural village"? However, there are 6,78,000 Google results for this phrase.

Comment: Where are you, since usage might vary by location? Beyond that, how about doing some more research. For example, list some examples in context to see if using "rural" is significant.

Comment: No, it's not necessarily redundant, given that Wikipedia actually has an entry for [urban villages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_village). But even if it *were*, that shouldn't be considered important - there's nothing at all "wrong" with most examples of redundancy in English. Or any other language - it's a natural characteristic.

Comment: Others have adequately addressed your actual question, but regarding your statement that "there are 6,78,000 Google results for this phrase" . . . please be aware that Google counts are generally very wrong. I'm actually not sure if they're even a *little* bit useful for this purpose.

Comment: In the countryside in the UK, there are some villages that are still  genuinely rural, and others which are populated mainly by commuters and second-home owners. In that sense a "rural village" might be defined as "if you go there between 8am and 6pm on Monday through Friday, you will actually find some people living and working there".

Answer (score 4):

No. While it is true that traditionally and "generically" a *village* is a rural settlement cluster in the country, nowadays *village* may have a technical legal meaning divorced from its traditional meaning.

In many states of the US, for instance, a *village* is a specific type of municipality, with specific powers and a specific type of governance. I live in St. Louis County, Missouri, the suburban sprawl around the City of St. Louis; of the 90 municipalities in the county, 22 are villages, governed by a board of trustees rather than a mayor. Some of them were originally rural communities which have been enveloped by urbanization; others are enclaves of a few very wealthy people.

Answer (score 2):

Does this seem rural to you?  [Greenwich Village, New York](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Village)

> [Village](https://www.google.com/search?q=Village&oq=Village&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i60&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=define%20Village)
>
> A group of houses and associated buildings, larger than a hamlet and smaller than a town, situated in a rural area.
>   synonyms:   small town, hamlet; More
>   a self-contained district or community within a town or city, regarded as having features characteristic of village life.
>   "the Olympic village"
>
> [...]
>   in the US a small municipality with limited corporate powers.

It's not redundant when it makes clear which of these two possible meanings is meant.

Comment: @Mari-LouA no problem. Hope to see you back soon.